# Mainframe implementation of SCIM

Tags: mainframe, scim

Does anyone worked on SCIM implementation at Mainframe technology?

Currently we are about to implement this SCIM approach on mainframe. Our master identity system is IIQ and ACF2 is the target system. Any one please share some thoughts about this implementation:

1. How to generate the ID tags
2. How to assign the Ref tags.
3. What are all the technical details to consider before going for this implementation?

Comment: Would you explain the acronym SCIM? This could mean more than one product or technology.

Comment: http://www.simplecloud.info/ is where I've heard this

Comment: is there a reason why you didn't the supported connector installation? I have done both SCIM and Mainframe installations - but I wouldn't ever use SCIM if a connector was present.